# How to update a table based on other rows in the table?

Tags: mysql

I have several rows in the `itemimages` table per each item. There is supposed to be a default image, so there is a column `isdefault` that is set to `1`. I ran this query:

```
select * from itemimages group by itemid having sum(isdefault) = 0;
```

to my surprise, I got a lot of items that don't have a default image
is there any way to update those items so that one of the rows (I don't really care which) gets `isdefault set to 1`, but not any other ones (exactly one has `isdefault = 1` and the rest have `isdefault = 0`)?

The table looks like this:

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
| itemid | imageid | isdefault |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|    115 |     167 |         0 |
|    118 |     176 |         0 |
|    128 |    9619 |         0 |
|    132 |     203 |         0 |
|    135 |    8040 |         0 |
|    141 |     223 |         0 |
|    146 |     232 |         0 |
|    148 |     239 |         0 |
|    153 |     256 |         0 |
|    164 |     285 |         0 |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you post your table's schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell not being able to see your table's schema, but I guess you're looking for something like this

```
UPDATE itemimages i JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(imageid) imageid
      FROM itemimages
     GROUP BY itemid
    HAVING SUM(isdefault) = 0
) q ON i.imageid = q.imageid
   SET isdefault = 1
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fddbb/1)** demo